# How to uninstall obsolete version of node.js from Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

I have two versions of node.js installed on my Ubuntu server(Ubuntu 14.04, node.js v0.12.4 and v6.9.2), the version 0.12.4 was installed through downloaded archive file and the version 6.9.2 was installed through `apt-get` by following [this](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/). However whenever I run `npm test` command for my project, it can't find version 6.9.2 node.js(which needs node version >= 6.x.x), what should I do to uninstall the obsolete version 0.12.4 node.js?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown) could be the solution. BTW, node.js LTS version is currently 6.9.1

Comment: `nvm` can only manage these installed by it, right? How can I solve this issue without installing any extra software?